# Mongo - MySql between like

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I make something like this in MongoDB:

```
select * from tbl_test where 1 BETWEEN start and end;
```

the below query doesn't work.

```
db.test.find({
    start: { $gte : 1 },
    end: { $lte : 1 }
})
```

Comment: what is 1 after where?

Comment: 1 is a variable value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
db.test.find(  { $and : [  {  start : { '$lte' : 1 } }, {  end : { '$gte' : 1 } } ] }  )
```

**Edited:**

in your documents `end` is greater than `start`, your query will give you just the documents which start = end = 1. replace `$gte` with `$lte` and vise-versa.

Comment: **end** is greater than **start**, your query will give you just the documents which **start = end = 1**. replace $gte with $lte and vise-versa. it should works fine